# ¿Cuál es la razón del error 'does not mean type'?

Tags: c++, herencia

Tengo un pequeño programa de árboles binarios distribuido en 4 archivos: main.cpp, arbol.h, loop.h y nodo.h.

Dentro del archivo main.cpp incluyo a loop.h, dentro de loop.h incluyo a arbol.h y dentro de arbol.h incluyo a nodo.h

Acabo de crear una pequeña función dentro de la clase Loop de mi archivo loop.h,  la cual es una simple copia de la función Sleep de la librería windows.h. Quiero utilizar dicha función dentro de una función  miembro de la clase Arbol que imprime los nodos del árbol en pantalla, es decir, quiero que cada que se imprima un nodo en pantalla exista una espera de x segundos.

Mi error surge cuando quiero crear un objeto de la clase Loop dentro de la clase Arbol o cuando quiero utilizar herencia, el compilador me genera el error "Loop does not mean a type".
Hasta ahora he intentado con herencia simple, clases amigas y métodos amigos. También eliminé la función de la clase loop y la declaré dentro de la clase Arbol para probar su correcto funcionamiento.

No incluyo detalles del archivo nodo.h ya que solo es una clase con la estructura del Nodo.

Archivo loop.h

```
#ifndef LOOP_H
#define LOOP_H

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "arbol.h"
#include<time.h>

class Loop{
private:
    Arbol Kyou;   /* 
                      Se crea un bojeto derivado de la clase Árbol,
                      este objeto lo utilizo para ejecutar las funciones
                      de la clase Arbol (como lo es crear un nuevo
                      nodo, buscar nodo, etc) dentro de mis funciones de
                      la clase Loop (como lo es pedir los datos del nodo,
                      etc)
                      E.g. void pedirDatos(){
                                cout << "Dame numero: ";
                                cin >> n;
                                Kyou.CrearNodo(n);
                           }
                  */
public:
    void esperar(float segundos){...}
    /* Más funciones que no son importantes para el problema */
};

#endif
```

Archivo arbol.h

```
#ifndef ARBOL_H
#define ARBOL_H

#include "nodo.h"
#include "loop.h" /* Incluyo el archivo loop.h */

class Arbol{
    private:
        Nodo* Raiz;
        int contador = 0;
        Loop mano; /* El error es este */
    public:
        void MostrarArbol(){
            mano.esperar(0.5); /* La función es de la clase Loop */
            /* El proceso recursivo para mostrar el árbol */
        }
};

#endif
```

El archivo main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "loop.h"
int main(){
    Loop l;
    l.loop(); /* Función miembro de la clase Loop que genera todo el programa */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno de los problemas más comunes a los que te puedes enfrentar mientras programas en c++ lo suponen las referencias cruzadas. En tu caso la cabecera de `Loop` invoca a la cabecera de `Arbol` y viceversa. Y lo que sucede es lo siguiente.

Esto:

```
#ifndef ARBOL_H
#define ARBOL_H

#include "nodo.h"
#include "loop.h"

class Arbol{
  Nodo* Raiz;
```

Se convierte en esto:

```
#ifndef ARBOL_H
#define ARBOL_H

#include "nodo.h"

#ifndef LOOP_H
#define LOOP_H

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "arbol.h"
#include<time.h>

class Loop{

    private: Arbol Kyou;
// ...
};

#endif
```

Fíjate que ahora, dentro de `Arbol`, hay una referencia a si mismo. Al expandir ese includes no se va a importar Arbol por segunda vez, ya que para eso están las guardas `#ifndef`.

Lo que sucede entonces es que en ese fichero la declaración de `Loop` intenta hacer uso de la clase `Arbol`, que todavía es desconocida puesto que se declara más adelante y de ahí el error.

La solución al problema se denomina *declaration forward* y se basa únicamente en decirle al compilador: "*mira, existe una clase (o estructura o enumerado o función) que se llama así, ya te daré en el futuro más detalles*". Con esa información el compilador ya puede compilar aunque con ciertas limitaciones, como veremos más adelante, esto último lo dejamos para más adelante.

El caso, ¿Como se usa un *declaration forward*?

Es así de sencillo:

```
class Loop;

class Arbol{
  Nodo* Raiz;
```

¿Qué limitaciones tiene?

Al no conocer el compilador el tamaño de la clase, ésta no se puede usar por valor. Únicamente se podrán declarar punteros:

```
class Test;
Test miclase; // no compila
Test* ptr; // ok
```

Como el compilador tampoco conoce las funciones que implementa esta clase no se pueden realizar llamadas a funciones miembro ni, por supuesto, llamar a `new` o a `delete`, pues éstas acaban invocando al constructor y al destructor respectivamente:

```
class Test;
Test* ptr;
ptr = new Test; // error
ptr->func();    // error
delete ptr;     // error
```

Y, para rematar, como el compilador tampoco conoce el arbol de herencias de la clase, los cast de c++ (`dynamic_cast`) también darán problemas.

Para poder hacer uso de todas esta funcionalidad es necesario que el compilador conozca la clase y eso solo se puede conseguir con el correspondiente `#include`. Como ya hemos visto que no podemos añadir la dependencia en el archivo de cabecera, la única solución es mover el `#include` al fichero de implementación. Los ficheros de implementación no suelen incluir referencias a otros ficheros de implementación, por lo que nunca se producirán referencias circulares en estos ficheros.

*NOTA:* Llegados a este punto, el problema que tienes con respecto a la otra pregunta del hilo es la siguiente:

```
#ifndef ARBOL_H
#define ARBOL_H

#include "nodo.h"
#include "loop.h" // <<--- AQUI

class Loop;

class Arbol{
```

Al añadir ese `#include` estás cargando `#define LOOP_H`, luego cuando en el fichero de implementación vuelves a llamar a `#include "loop.h" no se carga nada porque lo impiden las guardas (`#ifdef LOOP_H` detecta que el símbolo ya está definido).

Tu error se soluciona eliminando el `#include` del fichero de cabecera:

```
#include "nodo.h"
// #include "loop.h" <--- ELIMINA ESTA LINEA

class Loop;

class Arbol{
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por contestar!

Entonces, ya eliminé `#include "loop.h` y dejé

`class Loop;
class Arbol{
    private:
        Loop* mano;`

Pero al utilizar la función esperar con `mano.esperar();` o `mano->esperar();` me sigue generando error:

`Error: Foward declaration of clss Loop`

Comment: El `#include` lo tienes que poner en el fichero de la implementación para permitir que el compilador conozca el contenido de la clase `Loop`

Comment: ¿El fichero de implementación sería donde tengo el cuerpo de mis funciones de Arbol? Porque dentro de arbol,h tengo todo.

Comment: Pues deberías moverlo a un fichero independiente

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! He logrado hacerlo funcionar gracias a tus respuestas. Separé el cuerpo de las funciones en archivos cpp y las declaraciones las dejé en los .h
Ahora sólo tengo que investigar la manera de compilar esto con Windows, en Linux hice un makefile con las instrucciones y funcionó a la perfección.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es porque estás intentando usar un tipo **antes** de declararlo.

Según el orden de tus `#include` las declaraciones que ve el compilador son:

```
main.c
  #include "loop.h"
    #include "arbol.h" 
    clase Arbol { ... }
  clase Loop { ... }
```

Los `#include` son, literalmente, **coloca este archivo a partir de este punto**. Tu utilizas la clase `Loop`, en el archivo *arbol.h*, antes de que el compilador conozca su tipo.

Puedes pensar que incluyes `loop.h` dentro de `arbol.h`, pero su contenido está protegido por el `#ifndef LOOP_H` del principio. En `main.h`, al incluirlo ahi, defines ese símbolo, por lo que posteriores inclusiones no hacen nada (cosa lógica, o tendrías un **bucle** de inclusiones**.

Otro error que presenta tu código: La clase `Arbol` usa internamente una clase `Loop`, que usa internamente una clase `Arbol`, que usa internamente una clase `Loop`, ... aún no te lo ha mostrado, porque se queja de que le falta un tipo, pero lo hará.

Para resolverlo todo, tienes que **predeclarar** la clase `Loop`. En el archivo `Arbol.h`, tienes que añadir una línea:

```
#ifndef ARBOL_H
#define ARBOL_H

#include "nodo.h"
#include "loop.h" /* Incluyo el archivo loop.h */

class Loop; // AÑADE ESTO AQUÍ.

class Arbol{
  private:
. . .
```

Con eso, el compilador ya sabe que `Loop` es una clase.

Para solucionar el bucle en la definición de las clases, alguna de ellas tiene que dejar de usar `instancias` de la otra, y reemplazarlas por **punteros** o por **referencias**

```
class Arbol{
  private:
    Loop *mano; // Rompemos el bucle de instancias
 . . .
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por contestar!

Declaré la clase y el objeto así como lo habías comentado y el compilador ya acepta la declaración del objeto derivado de Loop, pero me genera los siguientes errores:

Cuando intento utilizar **mano.esperar(1)**

    [Error] request for member 'esperar' in '((Arbol*)this)->Arbol::mano', which is of pointer type 'Loop*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
    
y cuando utilizo **mano->esperar(1)** 
    
    [Error] invalid use of incomplete type 'class Loop'
    [Error] forward declaration of 'class Loop'
    
¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

Comment: Al declarar `Loop` como puntero, ya no puedes usarlo como hasta ahora, como una instancia; no puedes usar `mano.esperar( )`, sino que sería `mano->esperar( )`, es lo que te indica el compilador.  El otro aviso es porque, si *predeclaras* una clase, no puedes usarla hasta que el compilador no la conozca. Esa es más compleja, y requiere dejar de poner el *cuerpo* de las funciones en el propio archivo de cabecera.

Comment: Deberias de revisar el planteamiento de tu problema, de forma que no necesites esas clases anidadas; sería mejor `class Node { ... }; class Arbol: public Node { ... }` o algo así, que no `anide` las clases.

Comment: @akko revisa mi respuesta, al final de la misma tienes la solución al último problema que has encontrado.